# How to display all available options from .context import

Tags: python, windows, import, module

In certain python source code, the following line of code occurs:

```
from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
```

So what is this .context exactly is, 
and if there is an error in the line:
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
how can I know which part is going wrong?  and how to detect and fix it in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at [absolute vs relative imports in python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

According to your case

```
import .context
```

means that "context" module should be stored in the upper path relatively your python file.

There are some ways to fix import error:

1) Put "context" module to rigth path.

2) Change import statement with right path to "context" module.

Comment: Thank you ! how can I know what the "right path" is?

Comment: And for your second point, could you explain more specifcly about how to change to the "context module"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to use [mxnet lib][https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/python/mxnet]. Did you install it correctly?

Comment: Example of installation: `pip install mxnet`. After it you can use this lib like this: `from mxnet.context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned`

Comment: Thank you, And YES i am using MXNET but the reason I am asking for help is becuase Every time I try to import mxnet , the error above happens, and some dll is missing and I need to know which one is missing and how to put the corret dll

Comment: Did you try to re-install mxnet package?